# Bloqueo de CORS a la hora de consumir una API

Tags: typescript, cors, vuejs

Hola buenos dias para todos primeramente.

estoy tratando de consumir una API desde mi front con VueJS y tengo este error cuando lo quiero hacer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el codigo donde lo estoy consumiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo en el back donde le doy el permiso para que me consuma esa API desde los diferentes puertos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

son dos proyectos diferentes, entonces me corren por puertos diferentes, estoy tratando de desbloquear el CORS pero no he podido, espero me puedan ayudar con esto muchas gracias y feliz dia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo esta configuración:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Content-Type: application/json');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, x-auth-token, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
res.header('Allow', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
next();});
```

*Esa configuración la debes reemplazar por la que ya tienes, esto a mi me funciona sin problemas.

¡Espero te ayude!

Comment: excelente amigo muchas gracias por la información me ayudaste mucho